# How to get Intent values non Activity Class in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am new to Android. I have a base Activity class (MainActivity.java) which extends Activity. So I can initialized Intent here.
MainActivity.java

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ConnectionClass.class);
myIntent.putExtra("ServerName", ServerName);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
```

In connectionClass.java I have a class ConnectionClass which doesn't inherited. But I want to access the values from MainActivity.java. So this class Doesn't inherited Activity & onCreate Method. But I need to access the values from MainActivity.java to ConnectioClass.java

ConnectionClass.Java

```
public class ConnectionClass {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String ServerName = bundle.getString("ServerName");
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can only get the Intent in an Activity.  You'd need to pass it to any other class as a parameter.  But I think you're confused-  if ConnectionClass isn't an activity, you can't pass it as a parameter to create a new intent-  only Activities can be started via startActivityForResult.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the "ServerName" is fixed value, or varies each time, or it has a kind of pool of values. If it's the first or third case, I suggest you to use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). It's a relatively small key-value data storage. You can save data in it and it will be permanent in your app once stored unless deleted. So you can save data in MainActivity, and fetch the value in a class wherever you want.

You can find tutorial here : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the servername to the class when you are instantiating a new object from  ConnectionClass in your activity like below

```
public class ConnectionClass {
String serverName;
public ConnectionClass(String serverName){
this.serverName=serverName;
} 
}
```

then in your activity you have something like:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String ServerName = bundle.getString("ServerName");
ConnectionClass connection=new ConnectionClass(ServerName);
```